# How do you make a class fully static in Visual Studio 2012 so that it doesn't give any errors? - C#

Tags: c#, class, static, visual-studio-2012

I'm having problems with making the main class static which was not static when the project started. However when I follow instructions to make the class static and run it, it gives errors

Comment: What errors? Can you paste us some code?

Comment: Currently your question is unanswerably vague. It boils down to: "I'm doing something wrong. How do I fix it?" Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 2):

This has no errors:

```
static class MyStaticClass {}
```

Could you be more specific?

If by 'main' class you mean the one in which you define your main method, then make sure that all members of that class are also `static`.

Comment: It could use a few comments. I have no idea what your class is for. I just know that it's yours.

Comment: @Yatrix, haha, I literally lolled.

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda speculative at this point, but if you make your class static you'll have to make

- all its methods static
- all its fields static
- all its properties static
- just about anything about your class has to be static.

In general, you can't do anything that relies on the class being instanciated.

Comment: And properties, and events...